# Como armazenar perguntas e respostas no banco

Tags: android, mysql

Como eu posso armazernar perguntas neste estilo:

```
a.  __She__ is alone in the park, sitting by__herself___. (She/Her/Herself)
```

no banco com esses espaços para preencher e poder usar esses espaços no android por exemplo.

Answer (score 3):

Você poderia utilizar alguma marcação específica para indicar o uso do conjunto "__" e gravar na base com essa marcação. Quando a aplicação recuperar você poderia substituí-la pelos caracteres verdadeiros novamente.

Exemplo:

```
#### is alone in the park, sitting by ####. (She/Her/Herself)
```

Comment: Esses "___" é uma linha só pra indicar onde tem fica a resposta.

Comment: Você diz amarzenar tipo "textexto ___ textotexto" e depois fazer essa substituição do ___ no android?

Comment: Exatamente. Você pode utilizar marcações para indicar os locais onde os valores deverão ser definidos. Vou editar o exemplo que sugeri.